# macOS Sierra increase named pipe capacity

Tags: named-pipes, macos-sierra, capacity

```
mkfifo tmp
```

The `tmp` named pipe accommodates only `8192` bytes.

According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer) answer, the default size should be `16384` bytes switching to `65336` on large writes.

Not the case on Sierra v.10.12.4

Is there a way to increase the capacity of the named pipe?